# concatenate const char * strings

Tags: c++, string, char, constants, concatenation

I'm confused about `char *` and `const char *`. In my example I'm not sure how to put them together. I have several `const char *` strings I would like to concatenate to a final `const char *` string.

```
struct MyException : public std::exception
{
  const char *source;
  int number;
  const char *cause;

  MyException(const char *s, int n)
      : source(s), number(n) {}
  MyException(const char *s, const char *c)
      : source(s), number(0), cause(c) {}

  const char *what() const throw()
  {
    if (number != 0) {
      char buffer[1024];
      // why does this not work?
      cause = strerror_r(number, buffer, 1024);
    }

    // how to concatenate the strings?
    return source + ": " + cause;
  }
};
```

Comment: Why working with cstrings? Are you restricted to them? I would recommend you to use std::string.

Comment: Is this an exercise? If not you could make life easier with std::strings ??

Comment: Ditto, ditto. Use std::string. much better solution to most problems with cstrings.

Comment: @Zeta: it shold not thow ... during throwing, not diring contruction.
all the <stdexcept> classes derived from std::exception use std::string!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store a `std::string` and still return a `const char *` from your what function.

```
struct MyException : public std::exception
{
private:
  std::string message;  

public:    
  MyException(const char *s, int n) {
    char buffer[1024];
    strerror_r(n, buffer, 1024);
    message.reserve(strlen(s) + 2 + strlen(buffer));
    message = s;
    message += ": ";
    message += buffer;
  }

  MyException(const char *s, const char *c) {
    message.reserve(strlen(s) + 2 + strlen(c));
    message = s;
    message += ": ";
    message += c;
  }

  const char *what() const throw()
  {
    return message.c_str();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `strcat()` and `strcpy()` function from **string.h**.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/

Also, since you don't have to modify original strings, the difference between `const char*` and `char*` doesn't matter.

Also don't forget to `malloc()` (reserve the space for) the required size of destination string.

Comment: +1 for suggesting strcat instead of std:string. I'm old school.

Comment: You would leave the catcher with the responsibility of freeing the memory?

Comment: Many times malloc is imminent.

Comment: What if you lose the original strings before getting to `what()`? Or can it just be used with literals and global variables? This creates an interface that is just terrible. Using a std::string solves most of this.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the OP asked explicitly about the char* strings.

Comment: He did.  But I think as long as the input (the arguments to the constructor) is the same (two `char*`, or a `char*` and an `int`), and the output (the return value of what()) is a `const char*`, it fits the requirements.  If a `std::string` is used as an intermediary, that should be okay, and preferred if it makes the code's interface 14 times better.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'd implement this:

```
struct MyException : public std::exception
{
public:
  const char *source;
  int number;
  const char *cause;
private:
  char buffer[1024]; // #1
  std::string message; // #2

  std::string build_message() {
    if (number != 0) {
      cause = strerror_r(number, buffer, 1024); // use the member buffer
    }
    std::string s; // #3
    s.reserve(strlen(source) + 2 + strlen(cause));
    return s + source + ": " + cause;
  }

public:
  MyException(const char *s, int n)
      : source(s), number(n), cause(), message(build_message()) {}
  MyException(const char *s, const char *c)
      : source(s), number(0), cause(c), message(build_message()) {}

  const char *what() const throw()
  {
    return message.c_str(); // #4
  }
};
```

Things to note:

1. The original code was using a *local variable* for a buffer. That is a bad idea, as the pointer stored in `cause` would be [invalid the moment the scope ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794).
2. For the concatenated message, dynamic allocation would be required. And that also means that cleanup of that storage would be required. I grabbed an existing tool that does that and provides string-like operations: `std::string`.
3. With `std::string` concatenation can be done with the `+` operator. Note how I asked it to reserve memory for the expected size. This is memory an optimization, and is not required: the string would allocate enough memory either way.
4. `what` cannot throw an exception, otherwise a call `std::unexpected` would arise. So the string cannot be allocated here.

Answer (score 1):

If you must work with `char*` pointers, you will want to use `strcat`. `strcat` takes two arguments a `char*` and a `const char*` and appends the string pointed to by the `const char*` onto the `char*`. This means you first need to copy your first string over.

You'll want to do something like this:

```
char* Concatenate(const char* first, const char* second)
{
  char* mixed = new char[strlen(first) + strlen(second) + 2 /* for the ': ' */ + 1 /* for the NULL */];
  strcpy(mixed, first);
  strcat(mixed, ": ");
  strcat(mixed, second);

  return mixed;
}
```

Isn't that just ugly? And, remember, because you've dynamically allocated the char* returned by that function the caller must remember to `delete[]` it. This ugliness and the need to ensure the caller cleans up in the right way is why you're better off using a string implementation such as `std::string`.

Comment: And this cannot be called in `what` because `new` can throw.

Answer (score 0):

Allocate a buffer of size `strlen(source) + strlen(cause) + 3` and use `sprintf` to create your message. Actually you can move this code to constructor so that `what` becomes simple getter.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must use c-strings, you should look at `strcat()` to concatenate them together. However, since you are creating a custom exception, it would be reasonable to consider using `std::string` instead because it is more friendly to use in C++.